Unexpected result in floating point output
The following code:
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>

int main() {
    auto mod = 1e9+7;
    std::cout << mod << '\n';
    std::cout << std::fixed << mod << '\n';
}

outputs:
1e+009
1000000007.000000

I think that in this case, mod is a floating point number and so first one gives 1e+009 as output which may be due to floating point precision. But then after while using std::fixed, why the output is not 1000000000.000000 ?

Why did you expect that output?

I looked in my crystal ball and it told me that you're going to solve a competitive programming problem soon, and it requires you to give the result modulo 1000000007. Avoid floating point for that, it would get you into much more trouble than just printing the result in a funny way.

Any "challenge" that requires the result modulo 1000000007 is not supposed to compute the result and then do the modulo. Instead you should do the math first and see how the result can be computed directly. So it is a Math challenge and not teaching you any coding.

This question is similar to: Is floating-point math broken?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This using namespace std;  #define mod 1e9+7 with previous comments seems to indicate you're not learning C++ from a good source. (Where are you learning C++ from?). Don't use using namespace std; and if you need constanst use static constexpr double mod  = 1.0e9+7; But also learn about the limitations of floating point calculations first, this is a lighthearted but insightfull video  floating point numbers (Tom Scott-Numberphile)

@RichardCritten This question is very different. It has nothing to do with precision of floating point operations. It is about default number of significant digits that cout is printing.

The value stored in mod is exactly 10000007.00. It's just that when you print that value without any format flags, the runtime is free to print it in with a default precision that may not be what you expect.  Try adding a printf("%f\n", mod); statement into your program - you'll see that printf formats floating point values differently by default.

I think this is a good question (+1). If you consider it bad because the answer is obvious, please reconsider. If you are offended by the constant 1000000007, please try to be more rational! We usually don't explain –1 here, but if you think it's justified, please explain.

"due to floating point precision" -- This is too terse an explanation, as it assumes you know what is going on (but you don't, as evidenced by this question). Go to a deeper level of explanation, something at the level of "as I understand it, a floating point literal has at most nine decimal digits of precision [provide a reference, if available], so the 7 in the tenth spot is dropped". I'd also advise a read of [ask]; this question would be better if it had a more specific title and if it explained the scenario in text before posting any code.

"(All necessary header files included through #include<bits/stdc++.h>)" -- Was it easier to write this out than to start your code with #include <bits/stdc++.h> and have less typing overall (and have it be easier to copy-compile-run your code)? (Although, it would be even better if you used the standard #include <iostream>.)

The major feature of this question seems to be the assumption that a double cannot represent 1000000007 exactly. Without that assumption, this question would match several others, such as Precision of double in this code is only 6 digits - How do I display more decimals in the output console? - How do I print a double value with full precision using cout? I'm not sure if those should count as duplicates, given this question's starting point.


You should avoid macros when not strictly necessary. 2. You shouldn't/can't include <bits/stdc++.h> - that is not generally available. 3. You should avoid using namespace std. Changed all of that.


@Evg: Since that point is immaterial to the question, which itself is a valid question to ask, I believe it's better to comment and correct (which is what I did) rather than just comment.

What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?

1e9 + 7

This number is exactly representable in double, there is not loss of precision here.
However, when you print it using std::cout << mod, it is printed using default precision, which is 6 decimal digits. Therefore, 7 is not printed.
You can adjust precision of std::cout using std::setprecision manipulator:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << mod << '\n';
}

will print 1000000007

One thing I notice is that the question's initial output (1e+009)  is in scientific notation. Could you preserve this format in your answer, just with the increased precision? (This could be in addition to showing the effect of std::setprecision(10) by itself.)

It is not actually guaranteed that 1e9+7 is representable in double.   That is true for particular floating point representations (e.g. IEEE) but not others.    The C++ standard does not mandate using IEEE floating point and there are real world implementations that don't use IEEE.

@Peter: 1,000,000,007 is exactly representable in double. C++ inherits some minimum requirements of floating-point types from C via various references (2 Normative references [intro.refs] 1: “The following documents are referred to in the text in such a way that some or all of their content constitutes requirements of this document…”), and the precision C requires suffices to guarantee 1,000,000,007 is representable.

@IlyaPopov Thanks for that, could you please confirm whether fixed does more than removing scientific notation here(I am very new to coding  and could not find any online resource that could clarify the use of 'fixed')

@Lunatica Inserting std::fixed into an output stream merely alters the default formatting for that stream, that is, the way floating-point number(s) are rendered onto the stream.  It doesn't make any change to the floating-point number(s) themselves.

@Lunatica See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed
